Why did the Israelites only begin complaining about the Torah approx a year after its receipt?
Chazal explicate Bamidbar 11:5 & 10 that Israel was complaining about how onerous the Torah was.
This episode occurred toward the end of the second month of the second year of their leaving Egypt (ibid 10:11 ff), if not the 3rd month.
Per Chazal, why did they only begin complaining about the Torah so long after its actual receipt?

I believe the answer is preoccupation with Mishkan and death of Nadav and Avihu. If I remember a source in Chazal I'll add an answer

"how onerous the Torah was" is an interpretation, not the text, you should point it out.

The Kli Yakar asks this question

ולמה לא בכו בשעה שנאסרו להם העריות ואם באותו זמן שתקו וכל אחד מהם סבר וקבל עתה מה היה להם כי באו להזכיר ראשונות ולהיות תוהה על הראשונות שכבר קימו וקבלו.

After a long piece, he offers an answer based on a previous piece of his, that explains the parsha before (with the two nuuns before and after) as exhorting them to be diligent with the mitzvah of Pru urevu. Therefore, they complained now because they can’t do pru erevu as much of araiyos are assur. So it was a complaint that they can’t do both ends of the deal- do pru eruvu lemahadrin and refrain from arayios.
(I’m sure there are many other commentaries that discuss this, I happened to see this on Shabbos).

WHOT? What part of Arayos increases birthrate?

The part where one woman sleeps with more men

I think he means that the men felt it would be harder to find more than one wife if they can’t marry family

Any mention here of Yaacov's marrying sisters and Amram marrying his aunt? Seems logical that a people who have this in their history, finding out that it's against the Divine will, will have a push back of some kind. Maybe their complaint stems from "if Yaakov hadn't married sisters, half of us wouldn't be here!"
